# FQL returns only data specified as public?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is the FQL for their API only returning results that the user marks as public in the privacy settings?

I notice in the Graph API Explorer you are able to request certain permissions before running some of the FQL queries.  When I set those permissions, I can retrieve information I am looking for.  Is there a way to set those when logging in via any of the facebook SDKs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can gather the required Access Tokens (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) by requiring permissions (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/) while using Facebook Login (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/overview/) and creating an OAuth flow for your app.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  Much more helpful than a down vote.  I would have up voted it as well but I do not have enough reputation.